# How to copy a file from a subdirectory into another subdirectory?

Tags: command-line, directory

I have a directory, Documents with 2 subdirectories, A and B. I'm trying to copy a file from subdirectory A to subdirectory B.

Comment: So, what have you tried, and what was the results ? Are you usingterminal or file-manager app ?

Answer (score 1):

In Nautilus (drawer icon):

1. Navigate to your file
2. Right click
3. Select "Copy to …"

In the terminal:
`cp ~/Documents/A/[filename] ~/Documents/B/`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to navigate to directories in the terminal

at the prompt of the current directory (Subdirectory A)

type `ls` to display the contents. You can copy the filenames and replace the myfile ... etc in the below line with the filenames and then the path of the destination directory mydir (Subdirectory B)

`cp myfile myfile2 myfile3 mydir`